# Unable to view code coverage report on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, cobertura, software-quality

I convert my `.coverage` file to `xml` (using `codecoverage.exe analyze ...`) and then run [ReportGenerator](https://danielpalme.github.io/ReportGenerator/) to convert this file to a `Cobertura.xml` file.

```
...
 Creating summary
  Writing report file 'D:\a\1\s\TestResults\badge_linecoverage.svg'
  Writing report file 'D:\a\1\s\TestResults\badge_linecoverage.png'
  Writing report file 'D:\a\1\s\TestResults\Cobertura.xml'
Report generation took 16.8 second
```

Next I publish the code coverage summary file using [Publish Code Coverage Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops)

```
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
        # ------------------------------------------------------
        displayName: Publish code coverage
        # ------------------------------------------------------
        inputs:
          codeCoverageTool: cobertura
          summaryFileLocation: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestResults\cobertura.xml
```

I notice that this tasks generates `\html\*` using [ReportGenerator](https://danielpalme.github.io/ReportGenerator/) ([Sprint 150](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-150-update#cobertura-code-coverage-report-updates)).
When I check the *Summary / Code Coverage* on the Azure DevOps portal for that build I can only download the results? The task has created an artifact though..

[image: summary]

[image: artifacts]

What am I doing wrong?